# Ruby on Rails requests pending on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I do not know if this is a common problem or not. But I have a strange problem in my Ruby on Rails application.

For example in Chrome:

When I click a link_to or I try to change page it will load, and load, and load and the page won't simply open. To open I need to click open in another tab and close the current tab, that way the page will be loaded correctly. I don't know what the hell is going on, It just started to happen from one moment to another.

In Firefox:

The problem above does not happen but it does not show me the most recent html unless I refresh with F5. Then it shows all the content corretly except the first time.

I am using Linux to run my project and it is localhost. Both scenarios are very strange and I think they are related somehow. I already cleared both caches in both browsers.

Update:

As suggested made a search for turbo links. I have the gem installed but the only place where I am using turbo links is in `application.html.erb`.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Example:

When I click the Sign In property which is:

```
<li> <%= link_to "Sign up", new_member_registration_path, :class => 'navbar-link'  %> </li>
```

The call is pending and does not move (at Chrome), here is a picture of the network:

[image: Picture of the Network Status during the link to above in my application]

There is no prints at my console logs, nothing it just gets stuck and do nothing.

Comment: @Vucko I don't think I have installed anything in particular related to turbolinks. The other two options I already did both.

Comment: Does it say anything in `log/development.log`? My suspicion is that something is happening server-side, and turbolinks isn't picking that up for some reason. You are using turbolinks unless you explicitly turn them off.

Comment: try to load it on some browser without extension enabled (especially adblock). Try to remove the JS.

Comment: @Ven in firefox it works +-... in Firefox the problem is that some pages are never updated to the last version unless I use F5

Comment: @ChrisPeters Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.self-c5acd7a204f5f25ce7a1d8a0e4d92e28d34c9e2df2c7371cd7af88e147e4ad82.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-23 18:43:18 +0100

and nothing more happens

Comment: I'd suggest following Ven's suggestion of removing all JavaScript from the document `head` to narrow out that JS is causing the problem

Comment: @ChrisPeters I just have two that are listed in the problem description. I already removed them, but then the link_to does not link to anywhere but #

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Removing the turbolink feature from the application will solve your problem.
Here are the steps:

1. Remove the gem 'turbolinks' line from your Gemfile.
2. Remove the //= require turbolinks from your
   app/assets/javascripts/application.js.
3. Remove the two "data-turbolinks-track" => true hash key/value pairs
   from your app/views/layouts/application.html.erb.
   Cheers

Comment: Note that the point of the [Turbolinks feature](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks) is to make linked pages load faster. So of course if you disable Turbolinks, pages will load slightly slower for users (in the browsers that your app was working in).

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem could be related with Turbolinks.

To check if that's the case try to disable it and check if problems still occur.

To disable Turbolinks you can follow these simple steps (http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2013-06-25-removing-turbolinks-from-rails-4)